# Is it possible to take images of extrasolar planets?

Tags: imaging

Is is possible with today's technology, to take a photo of an extra-solar planet?  This applies not only to the visual wavelength (380-780 nm), but any wavelength.

Comment: Somewhat ill-defined. What resolution do you need? We can send probes...

Comment: Yes, even **way** outside our *galaxy*: http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/hubble/science/xdf.html

Comment: ^ now that is super cool. Anybody have any idea how far can we reach with the help of a telescope?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When will we have the technology to directly observe an exoplanet with significant clarity?](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/352/when-will-we-have-the-technology-to-directly-observe-an-exoplanet-with-significa)

Comment: This is a more general question than the "possible duplicate." It's got a simple answer, and that answer has already been given. No reason to close it now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.  Here is the first image of an extrasolar planet taken from 2005: http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap050510.html.

Comment: Sure i meant extrasolar planets, sorry.