# What is the state of the art of exosolar planet imaging in 2019?

Tags: photography, planet, telescope, exoplanet

I have seen [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/759/is-it-possible-to-take-images-of-extrasolar-planets) from 2013 asking if it's possible to take pictures of extrasolar planets. But I am wondering if anything has changed since then. **Have we taken higher quality images of other planets (outside our solar system)?**

Comment: Do you mind if I rewrite the title of the question to make it clear that you're asking about improvements in the state of the art? Occasionally people will vote to close questions as duplicate on the basis of the title question rather than what is said in the body.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I dont mind go ahead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia has a list of [directly imaged exoplanets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_directly_imaged_exoplanets). There are 22 of them and the latest one listed is HIP 65426, in 2017. It's image can be found [here](http://www.sci-news.com/astronomy/super-jupiter-hip-65426-05023.html).

Another example is GU Piscium b, imaged in 2014:

[image]

[NASA's Exoplanet Archive](https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/TblView/nph-tblView?app=ExoTbls&config=planets) has a list of 46 directly imaged planets. To show them, enter "imaging" in the box at the top of the Discovery Method column. I could not see the actual images on that site but, duck-ing (or googling) the host name readily brings up the planet's image - at least for the ones I tried.

Comment: Are the colors accurate?

Comment: Generally not. In most cases the observations are done in the infrared, because the light from the planet's parent star is slightly less overwhelming in IR than in visible light.

Comment: @Outsider RB's point is quite right, and also adaptive optics is usually (always?) used and that was originally developed only for the infrared as well, where the technology was easier to develop. See [Why aren't ground-based observatories using adaptive optics for visible wavelengths?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/14795/7982) and answers there. Please note that when we say "images of" it just means unresolved dots. As far as I know we're still *very far away* from resolved images of exoplanet surfaces.

Comment: @uhoh Indeed, we do not have the ability to see continents - or aliens for that matter ;-)