# Future plans and advances for improved extrasolar planet imaging; has anything changed since 2019?

Tags: interplanetary, imaging, space-telescope, observation, exoplanet

I have seen [What is the state of the art of exosolar planet imaging in 2019?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37061/12102) but answers there simply address the types and quality of images.

Here I'd like to ask about plans for future technology to improve the imaging of extrasolar planetary systems. I wonder what is "in the works" which may offer greater results.

Comment: certainly advanced spacecraft technology in the works including star shades deployed in space hundreds of km in front of a next generation space telescope, advanced coronagraphs, and gravitational lens-based telescopes. See [Are images of exoplanets' surfaces technically possible?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31768/12102) and also [What might the first deep space telescope using the Sun or Jupiter as a gravitational lens be like?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31815/12102) and [Can we make super-massive Telescopes to image exoplanets?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35396/12102)

Comment: Astronomy SE: [Why are there no photos of exoplanets?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32888/7982) (great answers) and [What kinds of technologies are required to directly image exoplanets](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/8847/7982) and [How could a 20 inch space telescope “be able to make out Earth-size planets” orbiting Alpha Centauri?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18726/7982) and [Is it possible to build a ground-based telescope that can directly image Earth-like planets orbiting in the habitable zone of sunlike stars?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34022/7982)